# three20 PhotoVC: editing rightBarButton

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, three20

I've created a subclassed TTPhotoViewController and presented modally in a navigation controller.

When I try to set the rightBarButtonItem, it won't change away from the "show all" button that would take me to the gallery.

I can set leftBarButtonItem but not right.

I tried created my own view controller which held the photo view controller, initialized it in VDL then set the frame and added subview, but I only saw white.

I want to use T20's functionality of auto-rotation, swipe to scroll, etc.. but I want to only show this detail view without the gallery, and let the user close it with a button on the nav bar.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at `TTPhotoViewController.m`, it appears that the "See All" button is created in a function called `updateChrome`; and it looks like there is no elegant way to override the creation of that button.  So the best option I can think of, although this is somewhat clumsy, would be to just subclass `TTPhotoViewController`, and override that function.  Either copy the code into your own function and tweak it (and don't call `super`), or call `super` but then assign a new button to `rightBarButtonItem`.

Answer (score 4):

it's too late but here is my two cents: subclass and override the didLoadModel

```
-(void)didLoadModel:(BOOL)firstTime;
{
    [super didLoadModel:firstTime];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil;
}
```